# Softmax activation function using math library

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to develop a softmax function in python for my backpropagation and gradient descent program. I am calling the softmax function after I get my outputs of the output layer (2 outputs), the outputs are in a vector-like so `[0.844521, 0.147048]`, and my current softmax function I have implemented is like this:

```
import math

vector = [0.844521, 0.147048]
def soft_max(x):
    e = math.exp(x)
    return e / e.sum()
print(soft_max(vector))
```

However, when i run it i get the following error

```
TypeError: must be real number, not list
```

Note:
I only want to use the math library and no others

Comment: Welcome to SO; please post a [mre].

Comment: The error is pretty clear. `math.exp(x)` expects a number not a list. And it also return a number and not a list. Also list doesn't have any method named `sum`.

Comment: @desertnaut err i have? you just need that vector and that function

Comment: You mean you added the vector *after* my comment, right? https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71539758/revisions That's cool anyway, voting to reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `math.exp` only works on scalars, and you can not apply it to the whole array. If you only want to use `math` than you need to implement it elementwise:

```
import math

def soft_max(x):
    exponents = []
    for element in x:
        exponents.append(math.exp(element))
    summ = sum(exponents)
    for i in range(len(exponents)):
        exponents[i] = exponents[i] / summ 
    return exponents 

if __name__=="__main__":
    arr = [0.844521, 0.147048]
    output = soft_max(arr)
    print(output)
```

However I still want to emphasise, that using `numpy` would solve the problem a lot easier:

```
import numpy as np

def soft_max(x):
    e = np.exp(x)
    return e / np.sum(e)

if __name__=="__main__":
    arr = [0.844521, 0.147048]
    output = soft_max(arr)
    print(output)
```